# NSTableView and hover over a column

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have an NSTableView implemented and want to add something where when the user hovers the mouse over a column, i display some custom info. about the info. in that column.
I am not sure if this is a tool tip or if there is an NSTableView delegate to do this.
ANy suggestions ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a tooltip.

Why are you unsure if there is an `NSTableView` delegate? Have you even *glanced* at the [table view documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/Introduction/Introduction.html)? Doing so would have answered your question faster than asking here.

You want the [tableView:toolTipForCell:rect:tableColumn:row:mouseLocation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView%3atoolTipForCell%3arect%3atableColumn%3arow%3amouseLocation%3a) delegate method.